# Cuda 4.2 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, cuda

I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu. I'm trying to install Cuda 4.2 on Ubuntu 12.04. I'm following the instructions found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Cuda

Has anyone been able to get CUDA installed using those instructions? The errors I get happen when I try the compilation of the SDK. This is what I get:

```
smaragh@ubuntu69:~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C$ LINKFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/nvidia-current-updates/ make cuda-install=/opt/cuda
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/smaragh/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common'
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wimplicit’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
In file included from src/bank_checker.cpp:15:0:
./../common/inc/bank_checker.h:34:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
./../common/inc/bank_checker.h:220:39: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
src/bank_checker.cpp:57:24: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
src/bank_checker.cpp:259:12: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create obj/x86_64/release/bank_checker.cpp.o: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [obj/x86_64/release/bank_checker.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/smaragh/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common'
make: *** [lib/libcutil.so] Error 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Fatal error: can't create obj/x86_64/release/bank_checker.cpp.o: Permission denied

Have you been trying to run commands as root or with `sudo`? If that is the case then note that, in so doing you have created folders you cannot write to. Try to delete the cuda directory and start from scratch.